# Adding int to NSMutableArray initWithCapacity

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, int

I'm trying to create a mutable array of two integers

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *myArray;  
}
```

initialized with capacity of two objects

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];
    [self addIntToArray];
}
```

and when I try to add an integer to my array

```
- (void)addIntToArray
{
    [myArray addObject:3];
}
```

I get the following error, and despite having run into this issue before and finding a workaround was unable to do so now.

```
Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id' is disallowed in ARC.
```

I tried casting my `int` to `id` and received an error stating I could not do that. I also tried initializing the array with `init` only, and still was unable to add the integer to the array. Would you please let me know how to implement the functionality I am trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSArray` can hold objects only. For storing numerical values, consider wrapping the `int` into an `NSNumber` object.

Comment: `array = @[ @1.0, @2.0 ] ;`

Comment: or if you don't know the numbers, you can use `[ array addObject:@<number> ]` (the `@` "boxes" the primitive value into an object)

Comment: Or if you have a variable of type `int` (or other primitive number type), use: `[array addObject:@(intVariable)];`.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, great to know there are so many ways.

Comment: @aug2uag FYI, all this is just syntactic sugar, i. e. these directly map to `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To Store any int in Array use

```
[yourArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:YOUR_VALUE]];
```

Comment: Or simply [yourArray addObject:@YOUR_VALUE];

Comment: You need to use NSNumber, as others have said, or use an NSString with the string representation of the number. It really doesn't matter which, but the NSNumber will be more efficient.

Comment: [NSNumber numberWithInt:YOUR_VALUE] and @ YOUR_VALUE, both are same. @ YOUR_VALUE is the literal representation of [NSNumber numberWithInt:YOUR_VALUE]